# How to write where clause and orderby sorting together in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does it have solution? When I read in firebase documentation, it said "You can only use one order-by method at a time. Calling an order-by method multiple times in the same query throws an error."

`let recentPostsQuery = (ref?.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "postType").queryEqual(toValue: "1").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp"))`

I wrote like that. But I found some problem. Does it have any solution? Thank.

Comment: You need to use queryEqual first and then queryOrdered and it has to be called one time. So the solution would be `ref?.child("posts").queryEqual(toValue: "1").queryOrdered(byChild: "postType")` and then use `sort` method after you get the data to sort the "timestamp"

Comment: You can't do that, as specified in the documentation. The queryOrdered:byChild defines the ordering of the data, and the data can only be ordered by one parameter. However, if we knew your Firebase Structure (as text please, no images) there may be a solution.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the problem you found and the query you want to perform? Is it posts ordered by timestamp whose postType value equal to 1?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: If i will write like below the code, will it cause performance problem when the data was big?
`let recentPostsQuery = (ref?.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "postType").queryEqual(toValue: "1")
recentPostsQuery?.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
 var arrayList = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
 if arrayList.postType == "1"  {
 //show the list
}
})`